# repeated measurmes anova

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have some measurements and would like to perform a statistical analysis. To make things easier, I will say I have 10 patients and I measure their body temperature when healthy, when sick, with drug A and drug B. This means I have paired data with 4 measurements for each patient.
- I guess the answer will be "no", but is it ok to compare always two measurements with the paired t-test, and why (not)?
- What would be the adequate test, repeated measures anova, if I want to test "healthy vs sick", "healthy vs treatment A", "healthy vs treatments B", "sick vs treatment A" and "sick vs. treatment B"? Looking at my raw data, I expect a sig. difference between healthy and sick, but not sure about the rest. Is there a post hoc test for rep. meas. anova?
Thanks!